# How to pivot multipe columns into two columns while retaining both the column names and values as row entries in python

Tags: python, pivot

I would like to convert the following table:

```
id   name    2002   2003   2004
1    name1   1      2      3
2    name2   4      5      6
3    name3   7      8      9
```

to this:

```
id   name    year   value
1    name1   2002   1
1    name1   2003   2
1    name1   2004   3
2    name2   2002   4
2    name2   2003   5
2    name2   2004   6
3    name3   2002   7
3    name3   2003   8
3    name3   2004   9
```

I have gotten to:

```
df1.set_index(['id','name'])
  .stack().reset_index(name='a')
  .drop('a', 1)
  .rename(columns={'level_2':'year'})
```

Which gets me the second table without the value column, what do I need to do to add the value column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the result using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function:

```
In [18]: df = df1.melt(id_vars=['id','name'],var_name='year',value_name='value')

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   id   name  year  value
0   1  name1  2002      1
1   2  name2  2002      4
2   3  name3  2002      7
3   1  name1  2003      2
4   2  name2  2003      5
5   3  name3  2003      8
6   1  name1  2004      3
7   2  name2  2004      6
8   3  name3  2004      9
```